# Finding Cov(X,Y) given pdf(X,Y)

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, covariance

Could you please guide me in the right direction for the problem below?

I don't know if I am right, but here is a headstart

Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)
         = $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} xy dxdy - (\int_{0}^{\infty} xf_X(x,y)dy)(\int_{0}^{\infty} yf_y(x, y)dx)$

```
from sympy import *
# Defining f(x, y)
fxy = E**(-x-y)
fxy
```

$e^{- x - y}$

```
# Defining E(XY)
exy = integrate(integrate(x*y, (x, 0, oo)), (y, 0, oo)) 
exy
```

$\infty \int_{0}^{\infty} \operatorname{sign}{\left (y \right )}\, dy$

```
# Defininf E(X)
ex = integrate(x*integrate(fxy, (y, 0, oo)), (x, 0, oo))
ex
```

$1$

```
# Defining E(Y)
ey = integrate(y*integrate(fxy, (x, 0, oo)), (y, 0, oo))
ey
```

$1$

```
exy - ex*ey
```

$-1 + \infty \int_{0}^{\infty} \operatorname{sign}{\left (y \right )}\, dy$

I am getting $\infty - (1)(1) = \infty $ as an answer.

**EDIT (Answer) :**

I have apparently made a mistake in writing E(XY)

Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)
         = $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} xy f(x, y) dxdy - (\int_{0}^{\infty} xf_X(x,y)dy)(\int_{0}^{\infty} yf_y(x, y)dx)$

```
exy = integrate(integrate(x*y*fxy, (x, 0, oo)), (y, 0, oo))
exy
```

$1$

[image]

Comment: If you do provide further indications than the definition of $\text{cov}(X,Y)$ on what is bothering you, the question is likely to get closed.

Comment: Can you share your attempt at the problem? So we know what area on the problem you are getting stuck at.

Comment: I presume your + which should really be - you have done correctly, given your answer of $\infty-1$. You might want to check whether your integrand in the double integral for E(XY) is correct.

Comment: @Mark Sorry, that was a typo. I have updated the description

Comment: @ZachTurn, I have tried to solve it programatically. I have updated my code for the problem

Comment: Have you reviewed the specification of the double integral for E(XY) as I suggested?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I can't thank you enough! It worked FINALLY